# Django version upgrade 1.7 to 1.8 - content type issue

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, django-upgrade

While upgrading django version from `1.7` to `1.8`, I got a new migration called `0002_remove_content_type_name`, after that I migrated that file, then I run my project, after that, it shows below error.

```
(1054, "Unknown column 'django_content_type.name' in 'field list'")
```

Then I checked the `ContentType` model in `django.contrib` files in packages, there I found the below code,

```
class ContentType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(_('python model class name'), max_length=100)
    objects = ContentTypeManager()
```

Due to the available of `name` field, I  got the unknown column error, We should not edit the package file(like commenting the `name` field list in the model file), also we have to `migrate` the changes given when upgrading django version `1.7 to 1.8`.

Give me the best solution to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete migration file and try again to migrate, also in case of repeating this problem - delete migration folder of the current app and migrate again.